# PrimeNG dropdown selected option resets when bound with interface property

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

This is how I've declared the `p-dropdown`:

```
<p-dropdown name="taxOptions" [options]="taxOptions" [(ngModel)]="purchaseInvoiceDetail.tax"></p-dropdown>
```

The `taxOptions` property is populated like this:

```
this.taxOptions = [
      { label: 'Tax Exclusive', value: '0' },
      { label: 'Tax Inclusive', value: '1' }
];
```

This is the `PurchaseInvoiceDetail` interface:

```
export interface PurchaseInvoiceDetail {
  id: number,
  product: Product,
  quantity: number,
  unitPrice: number,
  discount: number,
  tax: string,
  purchaseInvoice: PurchaseInvoice
}
```

The table is populated using `*ngFor` on an array of `PurchaseInvoiceDetail` i.e. `PurchaseInvoiceDetail[]`.

So a separate p-dropdown is present in each row of the table. The problem is that when I change the value of the dropdown and add another product the table refreshes and the selected option of the previous dropdown resets but not from the `purchaseInvoiceDetail.tax`. It only fails to fetch the value from `purchaseInvoiceDetail.tax` and show it as the selected value in the dropdown. 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dropdowns: Array<SelectItem[]>;


<div *ngFor="let dropdown of dropdowns">
  <div *ngFor="let taxOption of dropdown">
     <p-dropdown name="taxOption" [options]="taxOption" 
     [(ngModel)]="purchaseInvoiceDetail.tax"></p-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SelectItem Interface**

```
export interface SelectItem {
  label: string;
  value: number;
}
```

this is the pattern you can follow, just adapt it to your rows.

Comment: I've the `taxOptions` declared as `taxOptions: SelectItem[];`
It doesn't let me declared an array of type `taxOptions` like this:
`dropdowns: taxOptions[];`

Comment: Cannot find name `taxOptions`. I think its because we cannot use a variable as a type.